# Grails 1.3.9 to 2.4.3 upgrade - criteriabuilder changes?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

after upgrading from 1.3.9 to 2.4.3, we show query changes in the following code block

```
      criteria.or
      {
          isEmpty('targetSubs')
          targetSubs
          {
              eq('subscription', subscription)
          }
      }
```

This worked fine in 1.3.9 and produces no results in 2.4.3.

Was/is this a known issue or change?  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you switch from hibernate 3 to 4 or anything else?

Comment: I've tried the recommended hibernate 3 and 4 plugins and both exhibit the same behavior.  Hibernate plugin listed on the old app is 1.3.9